# Serial port names on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, serial-port

I am developing a cross-platform User Interface with Qt, and I need to communicate through a serial port.
I am able to use the serial port on Windows and Linux by using the following port names:

- COM1, COM2, and so on, on Windows;
- ttyACM0, ttyS0, ttyS1, etc, on Linux.

Now I want to do the same on Mac OS X. Do you know which are the possible port names on Mac OS X?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

They could be pretty much anything.  They'll *probably* be `/dev/tty.SOMETHING`, but there's no guarantee of that.  For example, my USB->serial dongle is: `/dev/tty.usbserial-FTG6RCEJ`.  The last bit of gibberish there is a serial number or something, I think.

Shouldn't you be asking the user for which port to use, anyway?

Comment: I verified on /dev/tty connecting my board. I get /dev/tty.usbmodem411 and /dev/tty.usbmodem621 on my two usb ports. I suppose I will get always /dev/tty.usbmodemXXX on any Mac. However, I should just check it on a different Mac to be sure.

Comment: No, you shouldn't be asking the user for which port to use if your user has no idea.  I'm working on such a project right now.

Comment: @Alyoshak Right on, ask the user and at best you'll get them coming here asking how to determine what the serial port name is...

Answer (score 3):

To use the programmer in Mac OS X, you will need to determine which names have been assigned to its serial ports.

To do this, open a Terminal window, type `ls /dev/tty.usb*`, and press enter. You should see two entries of the form `tty.usbmodem<number>` (e.g. `/dev/tty.usbmodem00022331`). These entries represent virtual serial ports created by the programmer.

The entry with the lower number is your programmer’s Programming Port, and later you will need to pass its name as a parameter to AVRDUDE. The entry with the higher number (which should be two plus the lower number) is the TTL Serial Port, and you can use a terminal program such as `screen` to send and receive bytes from it.

If you have other USB devices plugged in, you might see additional serial ports for those devices.

Answer (score 0):

Using an Arduino, one of mine is:

/dev/tty.usbmodemfa131

The last 5 characters are different for each port.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the serial port in OS X is dependant on the driver. It might be something like `/dev/tty.USBSERIAL/` and it might be `/dev/tty.PL2303-xxx`

You might wish to have the user create a symlink such as `/dev/tty.MY_APP_USB` that points to their specific serial port.

Answer (score -3):

many USB->miniUSB cables no has all pins plugged, only Vcc and GND. Them, cables may be the problem